# Separating VAR results by value of dummy variable

Tags: time-series, var

Suppose I have a dataset of this form: it is a time series dataset with some variables $y^1_t$ to $y^n_t$, and some dummy variables $d^1_t$ to $d^m_t$.

Suppose I make a VAR model where the variables $y^1_t$ to $y^n_t$ are endogenous, and I want to see how the coefficients vary by the value of the dummy variables.

My plan is to include the dummy variables as exogenous variables, and the interaction of the dummy variables with each of the endogenous variables.

That is,

$$y_t = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \beta'_{1, t-i} d_t^1 y_{t-i} + .... + \sum_{i=1}^{p} \beta'_{m, t-i} d_t^m y_{t-i} +\sum_{j=1}^{m} d^j_t + \epsilon_t$$

Once I estimate this, I can separately calculate the coefficients when each dummy variable is 1, and one where all are zero, giving me $m+1$ different tables of VAR coefficients.

I can then calculate the impulse response functions from each table separately.

My questions is, are there any pitfalls of this? Are the tables and the IRFs calculated separately for each table meaningful? Can I say that, for the table where $d^k=1$, it shows what would have been the IRF if $d^k_t$ were 1 for all $t$?

If not, are there ways I can answer this question in some other way?